# Cannot persist simple entity with Hibernate when run in an OSGI server(Works in a standalone Java application)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am just starting to use Hibernate-JPA. So do not know much in deep about how it works, though I know the JPA Specification to a fair extent.

I have a single entity Address, which has no relationships whatsoever. It has primary key ID which has a @GeneratedValue annotation and 4 other fields.
I instantiated the EntityManagerFactory, EntityManager, Address object and called
em.persist(Address);

I get the error org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.sac.hbn.Address.id.

I am running in an OSGI server, when run in a standalone application it works without any issues.

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9434 is the issue which I am facing but the asker there mentioned that when changed from 4.3.6 to 4.3.5 it worked for him. For me I tried 4.3.2,4.3.5,4.3.6 All gave me the same behavior.

This is the stack trace which I am getting.

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.sac.hbn.Address.id
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at com.sac.hbn.Triggerer.start(Triggerer.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 8 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.sac.hbn.Address.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 12 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.sac.hbn.Address.id to com.sac.hbn.Address
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 23 common frames omitted

And the address class is

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  private String street;
  private String city;
  private String province;
  private String country;
  private String postcode;

  /**
   * @return the id
   */
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  /**
   * @param id the id to set
   */
  public Address setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @return the street
   */
  public String getStreet() {
    return street;
  }

  /**
   * @param street the street to set
   */
  public Address setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @return the city
   */
  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

  /**
   * @param city the city to set
   */
  public Address setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @return the province
   */
  public String getProvince() {
    return province;
  }

  /**
   * @param province the province to set
   */
  public Address setProvince(String province) {
    this.province = province;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @return the country
   */
  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  /**
   * @param country the country to set
   */
  public Address setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * @return the postcode
   */
  public String getPostcode() {
    return postcode;
  }

  /**
   * @param postcode the postcode to set
   */
  public Address setPostcode(String postcode) {
    this.postcode = postcode;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Any idea why?

Solution : This worked through an unexpected solution. The thing was there was already a persistence Provider Eclipse Link configured in my Server. So it tries to pickup any bundle which has a Meta-Persistence tag in the manifest. I do not know how this is connected to the issue I was facing but as soon as I removed the tag, it started working!

Comment: please provide your Address class. It seems that maybe your getId() of Address does not have the required access level

Comment: There are  a number of possible underlying causes for a PropertyAccessException, including * failure of a security check; *an exception occurring inside the getter or setter method; * a nullable database column was mapped to a primitive-type property; * the Hibernate type was not castable to the property type (or vice-versa).  Please post more details like the full Stacktace and your Entity.  Otherwise it's hard to say if this is related to the linked Bug.

Comment: I have added the stack trace and the Address entity. The error I think was that two classes were incompatible, but I do not see why it is so. It fails at a call field.getDeclaringClass.isAssignableFrom(Address.getClass)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `setId` (and the other setters) must return `void`, and your JPA implementation is getting confused because they don't. Try changing them to return `void` instead.

Comment: Tried this no luck. The thing is ,if hibernate had a problem with the way I have coded, it should have failed when I run it as a standalone java application as well. But for me that works fine. Only when I run in the server I am facing this issue

Comment: @SachinCNambiar: not necessarily true, since the standalone version uses a slimmed-down implementation (reduced transaction support), and the app server supplies it's own implementation. Which app server are you using?

Comment: @SachinCNambiar: ...and are you saying you're **not** using the standalone implementation built into JSE (Not JEE), not even inadvertently? Are you sure?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by standalone version built into JSE..Hibernate jars I have added separately. I am using Eclipse-Virgo based server(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgo_(software)). This server have no built in support for HIbernate either. I have added OSGI bundles for all the required Hibernate jars including hibernate-osgi which was said to be required for Hibernate to run in OSGI environments

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can work for you

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {



    @Id 
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="cid")
        private int cid;
        public int getCid() {
            return cid;
        }
        public void setCid(int cid) {
            this.cid = cid;
        }
        private String cname;

        public String getCname() {
            return cname;
        }
        public void setCname(String cname) {
            this.cname = cname;
        }
```

Comment: No. Did not work with that either. At first I thought It was working because the initial error seems to be gone. But the thing is ,when the server starts and the program is run for the first time, it runs without errors. But after that If I run again, I get the same error. This holds for my Address class or your customer class